# Shopify Store Refresh cart content. AJAX request

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, drawer, shopify-template

I have product page on which I have `shop now` btn. When user clicks on this button, page opens cart drawer with custom ajax template content.

I rewrited click event with my own logic. I use AJAX and send request for adding product by myself. Products are adding but is not showing in the cart drawer. Only after reloading page it is appearing.

Question is to can I refresh cart content? I'm trying to past content template via inner html. But it is looks like not liquid format.

Here is the template

```
 <script id="CartTemplate" type="text/template">
{% render 'banana-stand-cart-top-container' %}
{% raw %}
<div class="drawer__scrollable">
  {{#items}}
  <div class="ajaxcart__product appear-animation appear-delay-{{animationRow}}">
  <div class="ajaxcart__row">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid__item one-third">
        <a href="{{url}}" class="ajaxcart__product-image"><img src="{{img}}" alt="{{name}}"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid__item two-thirds">
        <div class="ajaxcart__product-name--wrapper">
          <a href="{{url}}" class="ajaxcart__product-name">{{{name}}}</a>
          {{#if variation}}
            <div class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{variation}}</div>
          {{/if}}
          {{#if selling_plan_name}}
            <div class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{selling_plan_name}}</div>
          {{/if}}
          {{#properties}}
            {{#each this}}
              {{#if this}}
                <span class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{@key}}: {{this}}</span>
              {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
          {{/properties}}
        </div>

        <div class="grid grid--full display-table">
          <div class="grid__item display-table-cell one-half">
            <label for="updates_{{key}}" class="visually-hidden">{% endraw %}{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}{% raw %}</label>
            <div class="js-qty__wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="updates_{{key}}"
                class="js-qty__num"
                value="{{itemQty}}"
                data-id="{{key}}"
                min="0"
                aria-label="quantity"
                pattern="[0-9]*"
                name="updates[]">
              <button type="button"
                class="js-qty__adjust js-qty__adjust--minus"
                aria-label="{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.reduce_quantity' | t }}{% raw %}">
                  {% endraw %}<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-minus" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path fill="#444" d="M17.543 11.029H2.1A1.032 1.032 0 0 1 1.071 10c0-.566.463-1.029 1.029-1.029h15.443c.566 0 1.029.463 1.029 1.029 0 .566-.463 1.029-1.029 1.029z"/></svg>{% raw %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text" aria-hidden="true">&minus;</span>
              </button>
              <button type="button"
                class="js-qty__adjust js-qty__adjust--plus"
                aria-label="{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.increase_quantity' | t }}{% raw %}">
                  {% endraw %}<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-plus" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path fill="#444" d="M17.409 8.929h-6.695V2.258c0-.566-.506-1.029-1.071-1.029s-1.071.463-1.071 1.029v6.671H1.967C1.401 8.929.938 9.435.938 10s.463 1.071 1.029 1.071h6.605V17.7c0 .566.506 1.029 1.071 1.029s1.071-.463 1.071-1.029v-6.629h6.695c.566 0 1.029-.506 1.029-1.071s-.463-1.071-1.029-1.071z"/></svg>{% raw %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text" aria-hidden="true">+</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid__item display-table-cell one-half text-right">
            {{#if discountsApplied}}
              <small class="cart__price--strikethrough">{{{price}}}</small>
              <span class="ajaxcart__price">
                {{{discountedPrice}}}
              </span>
            {{else}}
              <span class="ajaxcart__price">
                {{{price}}}
              </span>
            {{/if}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid--full display-table">
          {{#if discountsApplied}}
            <div class="grid__item text-right">
              {{#each discounts}}
                <small class="ajaxcart__discount cart__discount">
                  {{this.discount_application.title}} (-{{{this.formattedAmount}}})
                </small>
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if unitBase}}
            <div class="grid__item text-right">
              <div class="product__unit-price">
                {{{ unitPrice }}}/{{{ unitBase }}}
              </div>
            </div>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/items}}

  {% endraw %}{% if settings.cart_notes_enable %}{% raw %}
  <div class="appear-animation appear-delay-{{lastAnimationRow}}">
    <label for="CartSpecialInstructions" class="ajaxcart__note">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.note' | t }}{% raw %}</label>
    <textarea name="note" class="input-full cart-notes" id="CartSpecialInstructions">{{note}}</textarea>
  </div>
{% endraw %}{% endif %}{% raw %}
   </div>
    <div class="drawer__footer appear-animation appear-delay-{{lastAnimationRow}}">
   {{#if cartDiscounts }}
    <div class="grid grid--full">
     <div class="grid__item one-half">
      <p class="ajaxcart__subtotal">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.discounts' | t }}{% raw %}</p>
    </div>
      <div class="grid__item one-half text-right">
      {{#each cartDiscounts}}
        <p class="ajaxcart__price cart__discount">
          {{this.title}} (-{{{this.formattedAmount}}})
        </p>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
{{/if}}
<div class="grid grid--full">
  <div class="grid__item one-half">
    <p class="ajaxcart__subtotal">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}{% raw %}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item one-half text-right">
    <p class="ajaxcart__price"><span class="tdf-cart-total-parent">{{totalPrice}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="ajaxcart__note">
  {% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | t }}{% raw %}
</p>
{% endraw %}{% if settings.cart_terms_conditions_enable %}
  <p class="ajaxcart__note ajaxcart__note--terms">
    <input type="checkbox" id="CartAgree" />
    <label for="CartAgree">
      {% if settings.cart_terms_conditions_link != blank %}
        {{ 'cart.general.terms_html' | t: url: settings.cart_terms_conditions_link }}
      {% else %}
        {{ 'cart.general.terms' | t }}
      {% endif %}
    </label>
  </p>
   {% endif %}{% raw %}
   {% endraw %}
   {% if additional_checkout_buttons and settings.cart_additional_buttons %}
      <div class="additional-checkout-buttons additional-checkout-buttons--vertical">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
   {% endif %}
  {% raw %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn--full cart__checkout{% endraw %}{% if settings.cart_terms_conditions_enable %}{% raw %} cart__checkout--ajax{% endraw %}{% endif %}{% raw %}" name="checkout">
  {% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}{% raw %}
</button>
</div>
{% endraw %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, need fire some event that you can find in your theme.js file. In my case I needed to add this:

```
 document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:build', {
    detail: {
      cart: cart
    }
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there is some way (js-function) that allows you to rebuild the cart with new items.
You need to check the js-code that is responsible for showing the drawer-cart

Comment: Yeah, thanks, for the answer found the way